# Can't create chart on JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsfiddle, canvasjs

I'm trying to create chart by Javascript on JsFiddle.
Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dataPointsA = []
  var dataPointsB = []

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/12qook',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(field) {
      for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
        dataPointsA.push({
          x: field[i].userId,
          y: field[i].numberOfusers
        });
      }

      var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        title: {
          text: "User Count"
        },

        data: [{
          type: "line",
          name: "line1",
          dataPoints: dataPointsA
        }]
      });

      chart.render();
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```

But when I press Run, it show only this:
[image: After run]

I'm new to this so can you tell me what's wrong in my code? Thank you

Comment: `userId` returned by the API is a string, but CanvasJS probably expects `x` to be a number, not a string.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I'm not familiar with Javascript so how I should fix the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render categorical data, use a bar chart instead of a line chart by changing `type` to `column` and `x` to `label`:

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/12qook',
  dataType: 'json',
  success(data) {
    new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
      title: {
        text: "User Count"
      },
      data: [{
        type: "column",
        dataPoints: data.map(
          ({ userId, numberOfusers }) => ({ label: userId, y: numberOfusers })
        )
      }]
    }).render();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/canvasjs/1.7.0/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 360px; width: 100%;"></div>
```